# How to test 16.04.2 HWE?

Tags: 16.04, hardware-enablement-stack

16.04.2 has a release date in less than two weeks, but I cannot seem to find the hardware enablement packages based on 16.10 anywhere.

How can I test the kernel and mesa changes that will arrive in 16.04.2 on a Xenial system?

Comment: Not sure about this, but maybe try the 16.04 daily image?

Comment: @edwinksl, no the xenial daily (currently) [contains](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xenial/daily-live/current/xenial-desktop-amd64.manifest) Linux 4.4 and Mesa 11.2. Not the 4.8 and 12.0 that yakkety does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official repos already have the HWE 4.8 kernel. The package is called `linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge`.

Starting from 16.04.2 the HWE updates will be "rolling". See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Nothing is announced regarding X.org update changes.

I do not see any X.org packages yet. Maybe this time the Canonical maintainers decided not to update it in HWE, because it causes lots of trouble in some cases.

But it is possible that `xserver-xorg-lts-yakkety` will appear in a while too.

Comment: Thanks, the name change explains why I didn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding X.org, it [has now been announced](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/mesa-13-0-3-ubuntu-16-04-lts) that 16.04.2 is delayed and will include Mesa 13.0.3. It is now [targeted](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2017-January/003998.html) for February 2nd instead of the original date.

The packages are still not in the archives, but can currently be found in the [X staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-x/+archive/ubuntu/x-staging).

The package names are currently of the form xorg-hwe-16.04.